# How do I mint an NFT without any image and and just some text?

Tags: nft, minting, metadata

I have made a script here to mint NFT as per the official docs. : https://github.com/nateshmbhat/cardano-nft-minter

But there is no mention in the doc to mint an nft with just some text description and a name.

How would the metadata.json structure for it be ? How does one browse or see that nft once its minted ? can someone please explain ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the [CIP 25 - NFT Metadata Standard](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip25/), an image is required.

You can, however, add some text to the `description` property.